# Search for a range of characters in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause, sql-like, glob

Assume the table is "t" and field is "f" and of type `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`. The SQL queries listed below work with `MS Access 97`. We are in the process of updating the database to `SQLite3` (long overdue!), and these queries return no results.

Is this feature to match (or exclude) a range of characters available in SQLite?

- SELECT * FROM t WHERE f LIKE '%[abcde]%'; -- match entries which contains 'a' to 'e' inclusive
- SELECT * FROM t WHERE f LIKE '%[a-e]%'; -- same query as above
- SELECT * FROM t WHERE f LIKE '%[^x]%'; -- match entries which do NOT contain an 'x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need the operator [`GLOB`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators) which:

> uses the Unix file globbing syntax for its wildcards

- SELECT * FROM t WHERE f GLOB '*[abcde]*'; -- match entries which contains 'a' to 'e' inclusive
- SELECT * FROM t WHERE f GLOB '*[a-e]*'; -- same query as above
- SELECT * FROM t WHERE f GLOB '*[^x]*'; -- match entries which do NOT contain an 'x'

There is also the `?` wildcard which matches exactly 1 char.

Comment: Thanks @forpas will check it out now. Is this `GLOB` syntax  specific to SQLite3 or will it also work with other modern SQL databases?

Comment: @AlainD I don't know any other db that supports the operator GLOB, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Looks like it works...but I note that `SELECT * FROM t WHERE f LIKE 'b_l%';` and `SELECT * FROM t WHERE f GLOB 'b?l*';` return the same results. How confusing! Do you know if it is recommended to use `GLOB` for everything (since it appears to be able to do everything that `LIKE` can do and then some more)?

Comment: @AlainD if applicable, like the case of `WHERE f LIKE 'b_l%'`, I prefer LIKE because it is standard SQL. One difference between the 2 operators is that LIKE is case insensitive by default (it can be made case sensitive with PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=1), but GLOB is case sensitive.

Comment: @AlainD also check: https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_like_optimization for optimizations when either of the operators is used.